# How do I replace carriage returns with <br /> using freemarker and spring?

Tags: spring, freemarker

I've got an internationalised app that uses spring and freemarker. I'm getting content from localised property files using.

```
${rc.getMessage("help.headings.frequently_asked_questions")}
```

For some of the content there are carriage returns in the property values. Because I'm displaying in a web page I'd like to replace these with 
.

What is the best way to do this?

Edit: looking closer it seems that I don't actually have carriage returns in the property files. The properties are coming back as single line strings.

Is there a better way to declare the properties so they know they are multi-line?

```
help.faq.answer.new_users=If you have not yet set a PIN, please enter your username and passcode (from your token) in the boxes provided and leave the PIN field blank.\
You will be taken through the steps to create a PIN the first time you log in.
```

Cheers,
Pete

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`${springMacroRequestContext.getMessage("help.headings.frequently_asked_questions", [], "", false)?html?replace("\n", "<br>")}`

Comment: Replace works. When I get a bit more time I'll investigate the idea of a custom directive as mentioned by ddekany. Until then this is doing the trick.

Comment: Peter, you would better make the appropriate FreeMarker `<#function/>` and/or `<#macro/>` and place it into an import library.

Answer (score 3):

To handle CR + LF (carriage return + line feed) line endings, as well as just LF do this:

```
<#escape x as x?html?replace("\\r?\\n","<br />",'r')>...</#escape>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<#escape x as x?html?replace('\n', '<br>')>...</#escape>
```

works just fine.

If you want this to be the default behaviour, consider writing a custom TemplateLoader as suggested in this blog: http://watchitlater.com/blog/2011/10/default-html-escape-using-freemarker/.

Answer (score 1):

As to the

> Is there a better way to declare the properties so they know they are multi-line?

part of your question, maybe this helps: you can include line terminator characters in your property values by using the `\r` and `\n` escape sequences, like it is explained in the [API documentation of `java.util.Properties#load(java.io.Reader)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29).

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to deal with this by splitting the text and adding a 
 tag between every new line like this:

```
<#assign splittedText = originalText?split('/n') />
<#list splittedText as textLine>
    ${textLine} <br/>
<#list/>
```

Comment: great, I feel stupid that I didn't think of this. Thanks!
This solution works well if you also have auto-escaping with output html!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend writing a custom directive for it (see `freemarker.template.TemplateDirectiveModel`), so in your templates you can write something like `<@my.textAsHtml springMacroRequestContext.getMessage(...) />`. It's important that this is a directive, not function, so it works properly inside `<#escape x as x?html>...</#escape>`. Otherwise it would be double-escaped. Using a directive can also give the highest performance, as you can directly send the output to the output `Writer`, rather than building a `String` first.